# Complex integral in all $ \mathbb(R) $

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to evaluate the next integral 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\lambda -ip)^n}e^{ipx}dp  \quad p \in \mathbb{R}  \ \ \ n\in \mathbb{N} 
$$ I don't know what strategy to follow, because I usually work with residue integration, but when  the function inside the  intergral is real.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer or a real number?

Comment: n is an integer

Comment: You should probably add it-- just for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four cases.

Case 1: $x>0$ and $\lambda<0$
Case 2: $x<0$ and $\lambda<0$
Case 3: $x>0$ and $\lambda>0$
Case 4: $x<0$ and $\lambda>0$

We shall examine Case 1 for which $x>0$ and $\lambda<0$.

---

Observe the integral $I$ given by

$$I=\oint_C\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}dz$$

where $C$ is comprised of the real-line from $-R$ to $R$ plus a semi-circle of radius $R$ in the upper-half $z$-plane.

The contribution to the integral from the integration over the semi-circle tends to zero as $R \to \infty$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_C\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}, z=-i\lambda\right)
\end{align}$$

For a pole of order $n$, the residue is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}, z=-i\lambda\right)&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to -i\lambda}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left((z+i\lambda)^n\frac{e^{ixz}}{(\lambda-iz)^n}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{(ix)^{n-1}e^{\lambda x}}{(-i)^n}
\end{align}$$

Thus, the integral of interest is

$$I=2\pi \frac{(-1)^n\,x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{\lambda x}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question to finish: If $\lambda > 0$ (which I know) what can I do?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  For the case $x>0$ and $\lambda>0$, there are no poles in the upper-half plane.  The result is therefore trivially zero.

Comment: Okey, perfect!! So I understand that for the case $x<0$ and $\lambda >0$  and $x<0$ and $\lambda <0$would be zero too?

Comment: You have it now.  Well done.  When $x<0$ we close the contour in the lower-half plane.  In that case, when $\lambda<0$, the pole is in the upper-half plane and the answer is  zero.

Comment: So, the solution would be similar to the first case, wouldn´t be?

Comment: Instead of having $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\lambda -ip)^n}e^{ipx}dp$ if I had $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\lambda -ip)^n}e^{-ipx}dp$ the answe would be almost the same, I mean, it would´t change the working proceddure in each case?

Comment: For the case $x<0$ and $\lambda >0$, the contour $C$ is closed in the lower-half plane and the pole is also in the lower half plane.  Thus, the answer is similar to Case 1.  But be careful.  The contour is clockwise and thus the integral is equal to $-2\pi i$ times the residue.

Comment: If the integrand were $e^{-ipx}$, then the problem is the same as the original with $x \to -x$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So in this case, when $\lambda >0$ we would have that: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\lambda -ip)^n}e^{-ipx}dp=-2\pi i Res (z=-i\lambda)$$ which is not cero  if $x>0$ and it is cero when $x<0$. Correct?

Comment: It is the most completed aswer I have ever received. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome.  It really is my pleasure.  I enjoy helping.

Comment: What I do not completely understand is how does the sign of x influence in the final answer. I mean I understand your full answer in case 1. What step couldn´t have been done if $x<0$?

Comment: Well, notice that in Case 1, as $x\to 0$, $I \to 0$ also.  And then as $x$ goes negative, $I$ stays $0$.

Comment: Oh, completely understood. Thanks once again! :)